# How can I enable my website to allow embedding in Sharepoint with just the web address?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, embedded

When adding a web address to a Sharepoint page (O365) using the Content Embed web part I get the error message:

> This website doesn’t support embedding using just the address. Try
>   pasting the embed code instead. If it’s important to embed from this
>   site using just the address, please send us feedback.

What do I need to do to update my website so it does support embedding using just the address?  Are there some meta tags I can add to the webpage?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? This question is the only hit in google that actually asks this the right way around and even the answer for this is exactly the wrong thing.

Comment: @Hippyjim No sadly not, though still interested to get a good answer - suspect this is one question that's really for the SPO developer team.

Comment: I tried asking in Sharepoint forums, and didn't get a definitive answer, but it looks like it might be using oEmbed. Unfortunately I've not had chance to try it though.

Answer (score 2):

**First,** you should add the address in an IFrame tag as the following:

```
<iframe src="http://mqassas/index.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

**Second,** you should `Permit to insert iframes from any external domain into pages on this site` by doing the following:

- Go to the Site collection setting.
- below `Site Collection Administration` > click on `HTML Field Security`
- Select `Permit contributors to insert iframes from any external domain into pages on this site.`

[image]

- Now edit your page that you want to add the Iframe.
- From the above ribbon > click on `Embed Code` > Paste your Iframe.

  - Or use `Content Embed web part`

[image]

---

> **Note:**
>   - Make sure that the address of the website begins with HTTPS. the only secured content is supported, the HTTP will not work!

Comment: Hi - thanks for your detailed response but this doesn't actually answer my specific question. I have already got the iframes approach you explain here working fine. However, I am looking for a solution that does not use iframes. The issue is that iframes have to have a fixed height and I want to add content that does not have a fixed height. i.e. there is a different height depending on whether viewed on mobile and on desktop. Without this you cannot add content below without having a large whitespace as you have to estimate the maximum possible iframe height.

Comment: Does anyone know what the real answer to this question is? I OWN a website and want to be able to give users a url they can paste into Sharepoint to embed things. Surely not uncommon?